# Software for hyper-v vm manager

Tags: virtual-machine

I have several `hyper-v` virtual machines and I want a software to show virtual machines in tabs ( like browser tabs! ) so I can switch between them quickly.

Comment: How much do you want to spend ?

Comment: @Marged Can you name some of those softwares?